# SQL select distinct rows and ignore row if blank

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using sql query to fetch rows from table. I want to select the rows only with distinct values and if there is no value entered for some row, that row should not be there.

```
SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE meta_key = "aaa";
```

This is the query I am using, I am getting the distinct rows by this query but also getting the blank row.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT meta_value 
FROM `wp_postmeta` 
WHERE meta_key = "aaa" AND meta_value != "";
```

Answer (score 20):

Try this query with `IS NOT NULL`

```
SELECT DISTINCT meta_value
FROM `wp_postmeta`
WHERE meta_key = "aaa"
AND meta_value IS NOT NULL ;
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use

```
where meta_key = "aaa"
AND (meta_value IS NOT NULL or meta_value != "");
```

but it's up to the engine you are using and most important - the way you are inserting empty values.
NULL <> 0 <> ' '

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT meta_value
FROM `wp_postmeta`
WHERE meta_key = "aaa"
AND meta_value != "";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle null value in `meta_value` column.
You can do like as follow.

```
SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'aaa' and meta_value != ISNULL(meta_value,'')
```

hope this will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In this query, different values are shown, if a column contains some null values are also removed.

"`select distinct color from tbl_product where color is not null`"

I hope this code is helpful for all..